# Filling PDF Forms

Tags: microsoft-excel, pdf, python, adobe-acrobat

I work at a law office that does a lot of work with USCIS which means filling out A LOT of PDF forms with our clients' details. This is often extremely tedious and repetitive, hence my desire for automation!

We keep a lot of this information in Google Sheets and elsewhere, but for now we enter everything manually using a combination of Acrobat DC and Mac OS Preview. These two get the job done, but at a high cost to me and my colleagues' sanity. In addition the bureaucracy of USCIS is such that every field that you don't need to fill out must be marked as "Not Applicable." Given the sheer number of fields, this is difficult to achieve and often leads to rejections/delays etc.

I was wondering if anyone has an elegant software solution or some sort of bash or python script to batch input the client's info in the right fields and put "NA" or "Not Applicable" in all unused fields. The former is preferable to the latter as I'd like to help my colleagues out and I don't think they are so fluent in scripting to make it work. Nor am I so fluent as to make a script work easily for them.

I've looked at these articles, but they are rather convoluted:
https://medium.com/@vivsvaan/filling-editable-pdf-in-python-76712c3ce99

https://medium.com/@zwinny/filling-pdf-forms-in-python-the-right-way-eb9592e03dba

Comment: Do you have any programming experience? In Python or Javascript? If no, find a programmer who can do this for you.

Comment: First and foremost a BIG WARNING: Never, ever, ever use Preview.app to fill out forms. This application is one of the securest way to destroy the internal structure of the form.

Comment: I have been involved in such solutions in the past; discussing them would, however, go beyond the scope of StackExchange; If there is interest, feel free to contact me in private.

Comment: I do have programming experience with Python and Bash. Max Wyss, how can I contact you in private?

Answer (score 0):

If you are not so strong in python coding you and your colleagues might consider either dedicate pdf soft or using using generic 'visual' scripting, automation or testing solutions. Something akin to Sikuli, WinTask, maybe M$ Flow https://plumsail.com/docs/documents/v1.x/flow/how-tos/documents/fill-pdf-form.html.
You can try pdf specific solution, like Acrobat or Foxit pdf form import/export, yet it might fails on some fields. Acrobat is not free and Foxit fails certificates which might be important in legal context. Also generic tool like Sikuli can be used in other automation tasks, like webworm filling.